# Select sum, group by, inner join, where

Tags: php, mysql, join, group-by, where-clause

I have a table from our cash register where clients buy stuff. It happens in our environment a lot that one client buys the same article.
Example:

| Client_id | Date | Article_id | Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 10 dec | 3 | 1 |
| 7 | 12 dec | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 12 dec | 3 | 2 |

Now I want to have a list like this (because client 5 has bought product 3 for 3 times in total):

| Client_id | Article_id | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 3 | 3 |

Also I need to know what product product 3 is, so there is a join structure set up from table Articles.

And a where clause, because I only want the sales from after a date.

All of that apart works great, but when I add them all together, nothing happens. Help? :)

I got this:

```
$sqlgegevens = "SELECT SUM(number) AS SumPerArticleProduct, 
                       articleid, 
                       price, 
                       number, 
                       client, 
                       salesdate 
                FROM Sales 
                INNER JOIN Articles ON Sales.articleid= Articles.Articleid 
                WHERE salesdate > '$date1'  
                GROUP BY client, articleid
              ";
```

Comment: What date you are passing, have you checked with `date_format('%Y-%m-%d', $date1)`

Comment: The date works fine. But thanks for the help!

Comment: Remove that number from Select, Sum(number) is fine, But don't take individual number field in select: $sqlgegevens = "SELECT SUM(number) AS SumPerArticleProduct, articleid, price, client, salesdate FROM Sales INNER JOIN Articles ON Sales.articleid= Articles.Articleid WHERE salesdate > '$date1'  GROUP BY client, articleid";

Comment: Incomplete grouping. If there is move then one value per group for `price`, `number`, `salesdate` then you'll obtain one indefinite value from all possible ones. Do you need in such "random" values really?

Comment: @Akina What do you mean with "random" values?

Comment: Imagine that you have specified `WHERE salesdate > '2021-11-30'`, and there are rows with the values `'2021-12-01'`, `'2021-12-02'` and `'2021-12-03'` for client `Client_id=123`. Your query will return one of there 3 values in a row, and it is indefinite what value of these 3 possible ones will be returned. I.e. one value from all existing ones to return will be selected "randomly".

Comment: Okay! I understand. Thanks for the explanation. How do I select those then? Because it is possible a client buys the same (or different) stuff at different dates. For the export, I need those listed per client, per article. So client 1 buys 3 article A and 2 article B, over 4 different days.

Answer (score 1):

You're breaking your `GROUP BY`-clause by selecting the `number`-field in both the aggregate `SUM(number)` and singular `number` form.

```
$sqlgegevens = "
       SELECT SUM(number) AS SumPerArticleProduct, 
              articleid, price, client, salesdate
         FROM Sales 
   INNER JOIN Articles 
           ON Sales.articleid= Articles.Articleid 
        WHERE salesdate > '$date1'
     GROUP BY client, articleid
";
```

---

Also, not directly related to your question, but you really shouldn't use variables directly inside an SQL query (and especially not if the value comes from userinput, which is even likely here): `WHERE salesdate > '$date1'`. I haven't seen your query statement, but it is likely your page has security vulnerabilities at this time.

See [Example #2 in the PHP manual here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) for a much better/safer way to query a database.

Comment: Thanks for the hint below. The date is from another table where the register is exported. The date from the export is this date, so no user input here :-)

Comment: ah yea. It's still best to use prepared statements for reliability sake (type info gets broken here for sure (such as if your initial $date1 value were to be `NULL` for example, that would be morphed into a `''` here), but yea it likely won't open you up to evil Bobby Tables in this case. (still worth doing it properly just to make that a habbit though, or it's bound to bite you in the butt at some point). Just one slip up and anyone on the internet can wipe or leak your entire database just by visiting your page once, and there are plenty of bots that crawl the internet doing just that.

Comment: Alright thanks! Will do.
But the query still doesn't work "Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object"

Comment: That notice is likely from a statement later on ? You'd have to show the relevant bit of code.

Comment: I did a num_rows() on the result of that query in that particular row. I just rechecked all fields and tablenames and they look fine.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, alongside with the double select from @Raxi, I needed to add the tables to the "group by" clause. It should be `Sales.clientid` and `Sales.articleid`. Now it works!

Comment: the `Sales.articleid` shouldn't have mattered, as the `INNER JOIN` ensured those values would be synonymous anyway, but if you had to add `Sales.clientid` then the problem was likely that you were using `client` before, and not `clientid`.